# Test if a given control sequence is a length register

Tags: macros, conditionals, lengths

I'm in need of a macro which receives a control sequence as argument and needs to branch if this macro is actually a *length* (of any kind, e.g. `dimen`, `skip` etc.) or "just" a normal macro (including one which is not defined yet).

```
\def\assignlengthormacro#1#2{%
   \@iflength{#1}{%
      \setlength{#1}{#2}%  or simply #1=#2\relax
   }{%
      \def#1{#2}%
   }%
}

\newlength\mylength % LaTeX length => TeX skip register
\newdimen\mydimen
\def\mymacro{Some other definition}
\assignlengthormacro{\mylength}{1pt}
\assignlengthormacro{\mydimen}{1pt}
\assignlengthormacro{\mymacro}{1pt}
\assignlengthormacro{\previouslyundefinedmacro}{1pt}% should still work
```

<sub>*Note:* I'm able to code it myself (using `\meaning`), but I think it is a good question and like to see other possible approaches. Maybe other high-rep users will wait a little and give others a chance to try it and earn some reputation points. *Bonus challenge:* make the test fully expandable ;-)</sub>

Answer (score 16):

Here is an expandable test for "skips" it could be extended to dimens in a similar manner:

```
\def\grabfive #1#2#3#4#5#6#7\grabfive{#2#3#4#5\ifx#6!!\fi}

\def\testforskip#1{%
\expandafter\ifx\csname \expandafter\grabfive\meaning#1!!!!!\grabfive\endcsname\skip
   \typeout{\string #1 victory}%
\else
   \typeout{\string#1 fail =\meaning#1}%
\fi}

\newskip\boo

\testforskip\foo
\testforskip\boo
\testforskip\skip
\testforskip\skipit
\def\skipthat{}
\testforskip\skipthat
```

This would give you:

```
\foo fail =undefined
\boo victory
\skip fail =\skip
\skipit fail =undefined
\skipthat fail =macro:->
```

My claim would be that there isn't anything expandable + safe that doesn't involve `\meaning`.

Comment: Thanks! Very interesting use of `\csname`! Again something I wouldn't have thought off.

Comment: Why `#6#7` and the `\ifx#6!!\fi`?

Comment: @egreg take it out and watch what happens

Comment: I did: the output is the same. As long as there are at least five `!` after `\meaning#1` there should be no problem.

Comment: @egrep if you take it out \skip will generate victory, no?

Comment: @egrep to say it differently a skip register would be \skip<number> on meaning, so the first token after skip can't be !. Thus if it is ! it means we saw the cs \skip on its own. And I added a bunch of !!!! just to ensure that I do not fail if the meaning is very short.

Comment: You're right. :)

Comment: @egrep pfff you got me worried ;-)

Comment: My worry with this test is that `\testforskip\foo` gives `\ndef=\relax`. So every call of `\testforskip` might have a date with the hash table.

Comment: @AhmedMusa true. Every test potentially adds a new hash entry but only one for one value of the argument. In the application that Martin had in mind he wanted to distinguish between csnames that are registers and those that aren't. So for each that isn't a register you create one extra csname once (and that should be a fairly small number). Its the price of being expandable without a machinery like expl3.

Comment: `\meaningskip` seems to be unused.

Comment: @HenriMenke true. Too long ago, but I guess it is just a leftover when writing the macro. I take it out.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a purely expandable non-expl3 solution for everything. I welcome suggestions of its failure modes. Because of the behaviour of the `\meaning` of `\count`, `\skip`, `\dimen` and `\toks`-defined registers, an expandable test for primitives isn't as straightforward as it might first seem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\@@empty{\@gobble\@@empty}
\def\if@cond#1\fi{\csname @#1\@@empty first\else second\fi oftwo\endcsname}
\def\if@blank#1{\if@cond\ifcat$\detokenize\expandafter{\@gobble#1.}$\fi}
\def\if@num#1#{\if@cond\ifnum#1\fi}
\def\if@cseq#1#2{\if@cond\ifx#1#2\fi}
\begingroup
\catcode`\&=7
\gdef\defregistertester#1#2{%
  \begingroup
  \def\x##1{\unexpanded\expandafter
    {\csname\expandafter\@gobble\string#1@test@##1\endcsname}}%
  \edef\x{\endgroup
    \def\noexpand#2####1{%
      \unexpanded{\if@cseq#1##1\register@test@a}{%
        \unexpanded{\ifprimitive{##1}\register@test@b}
        {\noexpand\expandafter\x{a}\noexpand\meaning####1:&}%
      }%
    }%
    \def\x{a}####1:####2&{\x{b}####1\string#1&}%
    \def\x{b}####1\string#1####2&{\noexpand\if@blank{####1}}%
  }\x
}
\endgroup
\def\register@test@a#1#2{#2}
\def\register@test@b#1#2{is primitive}
\def\ifprimitive#1{\expandafter\if@primitive\meaning#1\relax}
\def\if@primitive#1#2\relax{%
  \if@cond\if#1\@backslashchar\fi{%
    \ifdigitfound{#2}\@secondoftwo\@firstoftwo
  }{%
    \@secondoftwo
  }%
}
\def\ifdigitfound#1{\if@cond\if0\if@blank{#1}{1}{\if@digitfound#1\@nnil}\fi}
\def\if@digitfound#1{%
  \if@cseq#1\@nnil{1}{%
    \if@num`#1>47{%
      \if@num`#1<58{0\remove@to@nnil}{\if@digitfound}%
    }{%
      \if@digitfound
    }%
  }%
}

% Tests
\newskip\skipa
\newcount\cnta
\newdimen\dima
\newtoks\toksa

\defregistertester\skip\ifskip
\defregistertester\count\ifcount
\defregistertester\dimen\ifdimen
\defregistertester\toks\iftoks

\edef\x{\ifdimen\textwidth{T}{F}} % -> True
\edef\x{\ifdimen\hsize{T}{F}} % -> is primitive
\edef\x{\ifdimen\dima{T}{F}} % -> True
\edef\x{\ifskip\muskip{T}{F}} % -> is primitive
\edef\x{\ifskip\foo{T}{F}}
\edef\x{\ifskip\skipa{T}{F}}
\edef\x{\ifskip\skip{T}{F}}
\edef\x{\ifskip\skipit{T}{F}}
\def\skipx{}
\edef\x{\ifskip\skipx{T}{F}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\textbf{Primitive tests}\par

True: \ifdigitfound{a1c}{T}{F}\par
False: \ifdigitfound{abc}{T}{F}\par
True: \ifprimitive\muskip{T}{F}\par
True: \ifprimitive\hsize{T}{F}\par
False: \ifprimitive\textwidth{T}{F}\par
False: \ifprimitive\martin{T}{F}\par
True: \ifprimitive\toks{T}{F}\par
False: \ifprimitive\toksa{T}{F}\par

\par\medskip
\textbf{Skip tests}\par\medskip

False: \ifskip\foo{T}{F}\par
True: \ifskip\skipa{T}{F}\par
False: \ifskip\skip{T}{F}\par
False: \ifskip\skipx{T}{F}

\par\medskip
\textbf{Count tests}\par\medskip

False: \ifcount\foo{T}{F}\par
True: \ifcount\cnta{T}{F}\par
False: \ifcount\skipa{T}{F}\par
\def\countx{}
False: \ifcount\countx{T}{F}\par

\par\medskip
\textbf{Dimension tests}\par\medskip

False (is primitive): \ifdimen\hsize{T}{F}\par
True: \ifdimen\textwidth{T}{F}\par
True: \ifdimen\dima{T}{F}

\par\medskip
\textbf{Toks tests}\par\medskip

True: \iftoks\toksa{T}{F}\par
False: \iftoks\toks{T}{F}\par
False: \iftoks\toksb{T}{F}\par
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12):

A simple measurment of an `\hbox` should work. Unfortunately, this method may not work when `\mymcro` requires argument(s).

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\iflength#1{%
    \begingroup
    \setbox\z@\hbox{\ifdefined#1\expandafter#1\fi0pt }%
    \ifdim\wd\z@=\z@\endgroup\expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else\endgroup\expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi}
\makeatother
\newdimen\mydimen
\newskip\myskip
\def\mymacro{dummy code}% must not have argument
\begin{document}
\iflength\mydimen{true}{false}

\iflength\myskip{true}{false}

\iflength\mymacro{true}{false}

\iflength\undefmacro{true}{false}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I like this idea. I wouldn't thought about it myself. However, the fact that the macro is typeset etc. is a drawback.

Comment: it would break for quite a number of cases so it isn't something that you can use with arbitrary macro input

Comment: Another problem is that this requires fonts to be loaded.  If your current font is `\nullfont` all boxes will have zero width.

Answer (score 10):

Let me start with an unexpandable version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\IfLengthTF}{mmm}
 {
  \lentest_if_length:NTF #1 { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\IfLengthF}{mm}
 {
  \lentest_if_length:NF #1 { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\IfLengthT}{mm}
 {
  \lentest_if_length:NT #1 { #2 }
 }
\prg_new_protected_conditional:Npnn \lentest_if_length:N #1 {p,T,F,TF}
 {
  \regex_match:nxTF {\A\\??(skip|dimen).+} { \token_to_meaning:N #1 }
   { \prg_return_true: }
   { \prg_return_false: }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_match:nnTF {nx}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newlength\pippo
\newdimen\pluto

\IfLengthTF{\pippo}{\typeout{It's a length}}{\typeout{It's NOT a length}}
\IfLengthTF{\pluto}{\typeout{It's a length}}{\typeout{It's NOT a length}}
\IfLengthTF{\skip}{\typeout{It's a length}}{\typeout{It's NOT a length}}
\IfLengthTF{\xxeey}{\typeout{It's a length}}{\typeout{It's NOT a length}}
```

The output is

> It's a length
>   It's a length
>   It's NOT a length
>   It's NOT a length

One can also use `\IfLengthT` or `\IfLengthF`, when the true or false branches are not needed.

The regex matches `\skip` or `\dimen`, followed by at least one character, at the start of the argument's meaning. The `\\??` means that the backslash may not be present (it happens if `\escapechar` is -1; other possibilities for the value of `\escapechar` are not taken care of, but they could if needed).

---

Now an expandable test (thanks to Joseph Wright for suggesting it):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\IfLengthTF}{mmm}
 {
  \lentest_if_length:NTF #1 { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\IfLengthF}{mm}
 {
  \lentest_if_length:NF #1 { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\IfLengthT}{mm}
 {
  \lentest_if_length:NT #1 { #2 }
 }

\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \lentest_if_length:N #1 {p,T,F,TF}
 {
  \bool_if:nTF
   {
    \token_if_dim_register_p:N #1 || \token_if_skip_register_p:N #1
   }
   { \prg_return_true: }
   { \prg_return_false: }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Of course the `\IFLength...` commands are not expandable; but the `\lentest_if_length:NTF` test and its siblings are.

---

Why choose one or the other? It depends on what's the purpose of the macros. The second version can be made expandable, which might be desirable in certain contexts. The first version can be generalized in various ways, testing for whatever is necessary with a suitable regular expression.

---

Caveat: these tests *don't* distinguish among control sequences which are not symbolic names for skip or dimen registers and other control sequences. So `\IfLengthTF{\hsize}{...}{...}` will choose the "false" branch. It's impossible to recognize an internal dimen or skip register only via `\meaning`: one way might be to check the meaning against a list of the primitive names of the parameters (which might be added to the first method).

Comment: Did you look at using the `\token_if...` tests?

Comment: @JosephWright No; but they are too easy! :)

Comment: Nice example of showing the power of `expl3`!

Comment: @FrankMittelbach Do you agree with the form I used, particularly with respect to `\NewDocumentCommand`?

Comment: @egrep yes I do. Clear separation of the functionality provided, i.e., `\lentest_if_length:NTF` and the document interface (here using 2e syntax via `xparse`).

Answer (score 3):

Thanks a lot for all the answers. I also like to show how I approached it.
For a non-expandable version I would expanded the `\meaning` and read a predefined number of character to compare it with `\ifx` with a `\edef\SKIP{\string\skip}`. This can be repeated for several different values.

In order to keep it expandable every character can be compared using its char-code. This is done using `` \ifnum` ``, because  `\if` also compares the catcode which is set to *other* not *letter*.
This is basically a state-machine. At the end I check if a digits follows to exclude primitives with the same starting letters (if there are any) or `\dimen` and `\skip` itself (thanks to Frank Mittelbach who pointed this possibility out in his answer).

---

Here is the approach with one macro per letter. It assumes that `\escapechar` is non-negative, which is usually the case.

```
\def\@iflength#1{%
    \ifcase0\expandafter\@iflength@a\meaning#1\@nnil\space
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
        \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
}

\def\@iflength@a#1{%
    \ifnum\escapechar=`#1\space
        \expandafter\@iflength@b
    \else
        1%
    \fi
}
\def\@iflength@b#1{%
    \ifcase0%
        \ifx#1\@nnil 0\else
        \ifnum`d=`#1 1\else
        \ifnum`s=`#1 2\fi\fi\fi
    \space
        1%
    \or
        \expandafter\@iflength@di
    \else
        \expandafter\@iflength@sk
    \fi
}
\def\@iflength@sk#1{%
    1%
}
\def\@iflength@di#1{%
    \ifcase0%
        \ifx#1\@nnil 0\else
        \ifnum`i=`#1 1\fi\fi
    \space
        1%
    \or
        \expandafter\@iflength@dim
    \fi
}
\def\@iflength@dim#1{%
    \ifcase0%
        \ifx#1\@nnil 0\else
        \ifnum`m=`#1 1\fi\fi
    \space
        1%
    \or
        \expandafter\@iflength@dime
    \fi
}
\def\@iflength@dime#1{%
    \ifcase0%
        \ifx#1\@nnil 0\else
        \ifnum`e=`#1 1\fi\fi
    \space
        1%
    \or
        \expandafter\@iflength@dimen
    \fi
}
\def\@iflength@dimen#1{%
    \ifcase0%
        \ifx#1\@nnil 0\else
        \ifnum`n=`#1 1\fi\fi
    \space
        1%
    \or
        \expandafter\@iflength@dimen@
    \fi
}
\def\@iflength@dimen@#1{%
    \ifcase0%
        \ifx#1\@nnil 0\else
        \ifnum47<`#1 \ifnum58>`#1 1\fi\fi\fi
    \space
        1%
    \or
        0%
        \expandafter\remove@to@nnil
    \fi
}
\def\@iflength@sk#1{%
    \ifcase0%
        \ifx#1\@nnil 0\else
        \ifnum`k=`#1 1\fi\fi
    \space
        1%
    \or
        \expandafter\@iflength@ski
    \fi
}
\def\@iflength@ski#1{%
    \ifcase0%
        \ifx#1\@nnil 0\else
        \ifnum`i=`#1 1\fi\fi
    \space
        1%
    \or
        \expandafter\@iflength@skip
    \fi
}
\def\@iflength@skip#1{%
    \ifcase0%
        \ifx#1\@nnil 0\else
        \ifnum`p=`#1 1\fi\fi
    \space
        1%
    \or
        \expandafter\@iflength@skip@
    \fi
}
\def\@iflength@skip@#1{%
    \ifcase0%
        \ifx#1\@nnil 0\else
        \ifnum47<`#1 \ifnum58>`#1 1\fi\fi\fi
    \space
        1%
    \or
        0%
        \expandafter\remove@to@nnil
    \fi
}
```

---

I then coded a general macro for the repeated comparison. I guess the `parse` macro of LaTeX3 used in egreg's answer works similar, at least in principle.

Some test code is also included.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\def\@iflength#1{%
    \ifcase0\expandafter\@iflength@a\meaning#1\@nnil\space
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
        \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
}

\def\@iflength@a#1{%
    \ifnum\escapechar=`#1\space
        \expandafter\@iflength@b
    \else
        1%
        \expandafter\remove@to@nnil
    \fi
}
\def\@skip@or@fi#1\or#2\fi{#1\fi}
\def\@iflength@b#1{%
    \ifcase0%
        \ifx#1\@nnil 0\else
        \ifnum`d=`#1 1\else
        \ifnum`s=`#1 2\else
        \ifnum`m=`#1 3\fi\fi\fi\fi
    \space
        1%
    \or
        \@skip@or@fi
        \@iflength@cmp imen\relax
    \or
        \@skip@or@fi
        \@iflength@cmp kip\relax
    \or
        \@iflength@cmp uskip\relax
    \fi
}
\def\@checkdigit#1{%
    \ifcase0%
        \ifnum`0>`#1 1\else
        \ifnum`9<`#1 1\fi\fi
    \space
        1%
    \else
        0%
    \fi
}
\def\@iflength@cmp#1#2\fi#3{%
    \fi
    \ifcase0%
        \ifx#3\@nnil  0\else
        \ifx#1\relax \@checkdigit#3\else
        \ifnum`#1=`#3 2\fi\fi\fi
    \space
        1%
    \or
        0%
        \expandafter\remove@to@nnil
    \or
        \@iflength@cmp#2%
    \fi
}

% \skip
% \dimen
%
\def\@expand#1{%
  \par\string#1: \@iflength{#1}{\the}{}#1%
}

\begin{document}

\def\test#1{\@iflength{#1}{\typeout{\string#1: is a length}}{\typeout{\string#1: is NOT a length (\meaning#1)}}}
%\def\test#1{\edef\A{\@iflength{#1}{YES}{No}}\A\show\A}

\test{\test}
\test{\@gobble}
\test{\@nil}
\test{\@@nil}
\test{\textwidth}
\newlength\mylength
\test{\mylength}
\def\mymacro#1{test #1}
\test{\mymacro}
\test{\skip}
\test{\dimen}
\muskipdef\mymuskip=1
\test{\muskip}
\test{\mymuskip}
\def\mymacro{1pt}

\@expand\textwidth

\@expand\mymacro

\makeatother
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've corrected a missing `i` and the `\muskipdef\mymuskip=1pt`. The first was a typo, the second a real error: the syntax is `\muskipdef\cs=<number>`. In you case `pt` was simply printed. However, you can't assign a dimension in points to a `\muskip` register.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks, I didn't know `\muskip` much and thought it works similar to `\skip`. In this case I should rather remove it.

Comment: In e-TeX one can compare `\muskip` registers with `\dimen` or `\skip` registers, but it's a very crude comparison via `\gluetomu` or `\mutoglue` that convert 1pt to 1mu and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

This now available with the `etoolbox` package with `\ifdefdimen` and `\ifdeflength`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand*{\IfLengthTF}[3]{%
    {\ttfamily\string#1}
    \ifdefdimen{#1}{#2}{%
        \ifdeflength{#1}{#2}{#3}%
    }%
}

\newlength\LengthRegister
\newdimen\DimenRegister
\newskip\SkipRegister

\begin{document}
    \IfLengthTF{\LengthRegister}{is a length}{is NOT a length}\par
    \IfLengthTF{\DimenRegister}{is a length}{is NOT a length}\par
    \IfLengthTF{\SkipRegister}{is a length}{is NOT a length}\par
    \IfLengthTF{\UndefinedMacro}{is a length}{is NOT a length}\par
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just wondering, do you really need expl3 for the cs to string, wouldn't `\string#1` be enough? (untested, not at pc)

Comment: @daleif: I tried that and it was inserting a `"` before the name.

Comment: @PeterGrill That has to do with font encoding. If you use `\ttfamily` it will print ``\`` , and if you load `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` it will show also the backslash.